# Autolayout, View Height depending on subviews height

Tags: ios, autolayout

Using autolayout I'm developing a container UIView which contains a UILabel. I want to make the hight of the container view dynamically depending on the height of the UILabel.

I'm adding these constraints inside the container view, but I don't know how to tell the height of the UILabel because it's a multiline UILabel.

```
- (void) updateConstraints{

[self removeConstraints:self.constraints];

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_informationLabel);

// -- Constraints

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[_informationLabel]-5-|"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:@{}
                                                               views:views]];

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[_informationLabel]-5-|"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:@{}
                                                               views:views]];
[super updateConstraints];}
```

I've tried calculating the height with `boundingRectWithSize` and sending the height inside the metrics dictionary.

In the ViewController I haven't specify the height of the container view to let it resize depending on the height of subviews:

```
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-100-[_informationView]"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:@{}
                                                                           views:views]];

[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[_informationView]-|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:@{}
                                                                           views:views]];
```

How I can make the container view height grow as uilabel height has to grow?

Comment: container view should autoresize to proper height depending on that uilabel. Are you sure that you've put label as a subview of container? Maybe post more code how you're setting up all the views

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure the view is inside the container view, I print all the subviews and I can see it although the frame is (0,0,0,0).

Comment: are you setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` for all views?

Comment: @Axadiw yes, to all views and subviews

Comment: (you may have solved it already since its 10 days ago but anyway)
You most probably have another child item in the container that has is preventing that resize. Like an image with fixed height, with an To space constraint and bottom space constrains.

Answer (score 1):

The `intrinsicContentSize` of multi-line text (`UILabel` & `NSTextView`) is ambiguous. This is because the height depends on the width which hasn't yet been calculated. To solve this, you have to allow a first pass of layout, and then set the newly added property `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` which solves this problem specifically.

```
// Inside superview
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  [super layoutSubviews];
  self.informationLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.informationLabel.frame.size.width;
  [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

*Source:* http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html